# Intent for opening url creates new instance

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I added an intent filter in the Android Manifest to handle intents for opening a URL:

```
<activity android:name=".TestActivity"
    android:label="Test" android:theme="@style/Theme.Titanium"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="test.com" />
    </intent-filter>                
</activity>
```

The issue I have is when the App is already open, this code launches a new instance of the App which can be very confusing to the user.  After the launching the new instance, if the user navigates away using the Home Button and then returns to the App, they see the 1st instance. How can I Fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
```

Comment: The issue I have with adding this is that when a user navigates away using the Home Button while NOT on the Main Activity, when the user returns to the App, they are shown the Main Activity.  They should be presented the last activity they were on when returning.